# SMTP email for office365

Tags: python, smtp, smtplib

I want to send an email through python, I followed the below code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46160886/how-to-send-smtp-email-for-office365-with-python-using-tls-ssl) link:

```
import smtplib

mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com',587)
mailserver.ehlo()
mailserver.starttls()
mailserver.login('myemail@company.com', 'mypassword')
msg = ('this is a message')
mailserver.sendmail('myemail@company.com','receiver@company.com',msg)
```

The issue: 
The email is in my sentbox, and the receiver's inbox, however there is no text. It is empty.

There is no error, or output, the script just runs, so I am unsure where to start troubleshooting, as I am not an expert in this area; could anyone explain why there is no message/text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `\n` between subject and email body in the 3rd argument to `sendmail`

```
msg = 'Subject: Email Subject.\n{}'.format('this is a message')
mailserver.sendmail('myemail@company.com','receiver@company.com', msg)
```

Comment: Thanks, so now it prints 'Email Subject.', but it doesn't print 'this is a message'

Comment: actually thanks, i just added in a few more new lines and it works.